# Emojis have same value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm Creating a `slot machine` using `emojis` in `reactjs`

*The main problem is*:

**I'm getting the same value for emoji and only one condition is applied to if-else that means I have only getting this is matching when every emoji is different**

```
import React from "react";

const SlotM = (props) => {
  //let x = "";
  //let y = "";
  //let z = "";

  let emoji = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];

  let random = (mn, mx) => {
    return Math.random() * (mx - mn) + mn;
  };

  let onClic = () => {
    return emoji[Math.floor(random(1, 9)) - 1];
  };

  let { x = onClic(), y = onClic(), z = onClic() } = props;

  console.log(x, y, z);
  if (props.x === props.y && props.y === props.z) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="slot_inner">
          <h1>
            {x} {y} {z}
          </h1>
          <h1>This is mathcing</h1>
          {console.log(x.charCodeAt(), y, z)}
          <hr />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="slot_inner">
          <h1>
            {x} {y} {z}
          </h1>
          <h1>This is not mathcing</h1>
          <hr />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
};

export default SlotM;
```

How can resolve this problem..!?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), How you use the component? What are you passing? What are you getting?

Comment: I'm passing props and I'm getting only one output from if-else top one "this is matching" I think the ASCII value of every emoji is the same

Comment: First you don't have "this is matching" text, second, please share code read the link.

Comment: sorry Dennis my bad

Comment: This will also help you reproduce your issue within the question: [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537)

Comment: I log the ASCII value of every emoji and it is the same maybe that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to pass the param to the SlotM.
See my working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-franklin-7lq64?file=/src/App.js
Notice how I passed the props:

```
      <SlotM x="" y="" z="" />
      <SlotM x="" y="" z="" />
```

Comment: you already hardcoded it and I want it on a random basis when I click on the button thanks :)

Comment: Is it ok now? https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-franklin-7lq64?file=/src/App.js